# Publish app in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I try to update customers App in Google Play, this is my first time I do this.

I created a certificate, it seems to be fine. The app was packaged with appcelerator titanium.

When I upload the app in store I get this message:

The name ofupdated APK-Package (gdp.app) must be the same with the package I want to replace (de.gdp)

File Name I upload is: GdP.apk

What do I have to change?

Comment: you changed the package name in the manifest..it used to be "de.gdp", and now it is "gdp.app"..you cannot update your application with different package name since it is regarded as a unique identifier

Comment: Thank you, I simply had no idea where to search :) Thanks to you I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the package name. You have to use the same package name as the original .apk. 
Change your package name back to de.gdp .

More information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: What I have to do, if I do not have the same certificate any more?

Comment: A strategy for the future is to store your certificates with your code, in your source repository.

Answer (score 2):

"I wont to replace (de.gdp)"

well, you cannot rename your package. If you change your package name the store recognizes it as a different app.
so you cannot update it with different package name. 
Renaming your package to gdp.app will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not offer it to existing users as an update.
So, you have to maintain the same package name of previous build.

See this link: http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.in/2012/07/upload-apk-into-android-market.html

Comment: What I have to do, if I do not have the same certificate any more?

Comment: If you lost your certificate.. Then there is no possibility to update your App in Market. The only solution is, change the package name and Upload as a new APP.